# How to Scan iBeacon in Android Wear (Ambient Mode)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, wear-os, ibeacon

I'm trying to detect in-door location in Android Wear.

First, I am using iBeacon to detecting where I am.
And I succeed to get location in interactive mode.

Next, I would like to continue searching iBeacons in ambient mode.
But I can't search because Application ends.

Please help me ;(

--info--
I'm using org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+ in gradle.

```
public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity implements BeaconConsumer {

private TextView mTextView;private static String TAG = "AltBeacon Sample";
private BeaconManager beaconManager;

/** Parser format to detect iBeacons */
public static final String IBEACON_FORMAT = "m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24";


/** TextViews */
private TextView mTitleView;
private TextView mRSSIView;
private TextView mMajorView;
private TextView mMinorView;
private TextView mMajorLabel;
private TextView mMinorLabel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "==========================iBeaconWear==========================");
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateメソッドが実行されました");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setAmbientEnabled();

    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {

            mTitleView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
            mMajorView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.majorText);
            mMinorView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.minorText);
            mRSSIView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            mMajorLabel = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            mMinorLabel = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

            mTitleView.setText("iBeacon Finder");


        }
    });

    // staticメソッドでBeaconManagerクラスのインスタンスを取得
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(10000l);              //フォアグラウンドのスキャン間隔
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(10000l);              //バックグラウンドのスキャン間隔
    // BeaconParseをBeaconManagerに設定
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(IBEACON_FORMAT));

}


@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    // BeaconManagerクラスのモニタリング設定


    beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
            // 領域侵入時に実行
            Log.d(TAG, "==========================領域に侵入==========================");

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    //UI操作するコードをここに書く
                    TextView statusTextView;
                    statusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    //statusTextView.setText("Beacon In Range!!");
                }
            });


            try {

                // UUIDの作成
                Identifier identifier = Identifier.parse("00000000-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX");
                // レンジングの開始
                beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("unique-id-001", identifier, null, null));
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // 例外が発生した場合
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
            // 領域退出時に実行
            Log.d(TAG, "==========================領域から退出==========================");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    //UI操作するコードをここに書く
                    TextView statusTextView;
                    statusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    //statusTextView.setText("Beacon Out of Range!!");
                }
            });

            try {

                // UUIDの作成
                Identifier identifier = Identifier.parse("00000000-78AD-1001-B000-001C4D0A7205");
                // レンジングの停止
                beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("unique-id-001", identifier, null, null));
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // 例外が発生した場合
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {
            // 領域への侵入/退出のステータスが変化したときに実行
            Log.d(TAG, "==========================領域ステータス変更==========================");
        }
    });

    // BeaconManagerクラスのレンジング設定
    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            // 検出したビーコンの情報を全部Logに書き出す
            for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                Log.d(TAG, "UUID:" + beacon.getId1() + ", major:" + beacon.getId2() + ", minor:" + beacon.getId3() + ", Distance:" + beacon.getDistance() + ",RSSI" + beacon.getRssi() + ", TxPower" + beacon.getTxPower());

                final Beacon beaconInfo = beacon;

                /**runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //UI操作するコードをここに書く
                        TextView statusTextView;
                        statusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                        statusTextView.setText("RSSI:" + beaconInfo.getRssi());

                        TextView majorTextView;
                        majorTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.majorText);
                        majorTextView.setText("" + beaconInfo.getId2());

                        TextView minorTextView;
                        minorTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minorText);
                        minorTextView.setText("" + beaconInfo.getId3());


                    }
                });*/
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        // UUIDの作成
        Identifier identifier = Identifier.parse("00000000-78AD-1001-B000-001C4D0A7205");
        // モニタリングの開始
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("unique-id-001", identifier, null, null));
    } catch(RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onPause();
    beaconManager.bind(this);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy()");


    super.onDestroy();


}


@Override
public void onEnterAmbient(Bundle ambientDetails) {
    Log.d(TAG, "==========================iBeaconWear==========================");
    Log.d(TAG, "アンビエントモードに入りました");
    super.onEnterAmbient(ambientDetails);

    mTitleView.getPaint().setAntiAlias(false);
    mRSSIView.getPaint().setAntiAlias(false);
    mMinorLabel.getPaint().setAntiAlias(false);
    mMajorView.getPaint().setAntiAlias(false);
    mMinorLabel.getPaint().setAntiAlias(false);
    mMinorView.getPaint().setAntiAlias(false);

    //beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true);

}

@Override
public void onUpdateAmbient() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onUpdateAmbient()");
    super.onUpdateAmbient();



}

/**
 * Prepares UI for Active view (non-Ambient).
 */
@Override
public void onExitAmbient() {
    Log.d(TAG, "==========================iBeaconWear==========================");
    Log.d(TAG, "インタラクティブモードに入りました");
    super.onExitAmbient();

    mTitleView.getPaint().setAntiAlias(true);
    mRSSIView.getPaint().setAntiAlias(true);
    mMinorLabel.getPaint().setAntiAlias(true);
    mMajorView.getPaint().setAntiAlias(true);
    mMinorLabel.getPaint().setAntiAlias(true);
    mMinorView.getPaint().setAntiAlias(true);

    //beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(false);
}


}
```

Here's the stack trace

```
07-09 13:26:08.925: E/GpsXtraDownloader(419): No XTRA servers were specified in the GPS configuration
07-09 13:26:15.277: D/AndroidRuntime(21050): >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
07-09 13:26:15.283: D/AndroidRuntime(21050): CheckJNI is OFF
07-09 13:26:15.361: E/cutils-trace(21050): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-09 13:26:15.446: E/memtrack(21050): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-09 13:26:15.446: E/android.os.Debug(21050): failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-09 13:26:15.525: D/AndroidRuntime(21050): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
07-09 13:26:15.537: I/ActivityManager(419): Force stopping com.example.pittan.androidwearble appid=10023 user=0: from pid 21050
07-09 13:26:15.537: I/ActivityManager(419): Killing 20490:com.example.pittan.androidwearble/u0a23 (adj 7): stop com.example.pittan.androidwearble
07-09 13:26:15.607: I/WindowState(419): WIN DEATH: Window{17c36a4e u0 com.example.pittan.androidwearble/com.example.pittan.androidwearble.MainActivity}
07-09 13:26:15.649: I/ActivityManager(419):   Force finishing activity 3 ActivityRecord{3f1a6095 u0 com.example.pittan.androidwearble/.MainActivity t385}
07-09 13:26:15.652: W/ActivityManager(419): Spurious death for ProcessRecord{c58dd38 20490:com.example.pittan.androidwearble/u0a23}, curProc for 20490: null
07-09 13:26:15.653: D/AndroidRuntime(21050): Shutting down VM
07-09 13:26:15.663: I/art(21050): Debugger is no longer active
07-09 13:26:16.277: D/AndroidRuntime(21072): >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
07-09 13:26:16.283: D/AndroidRuntime(21072): CheckJNI is OFF
07-09 13:26:16.362: E/cutils-trace(21072): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-09 13:26:16.455: E/memtrack(21072): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-09 13:26:16.455: E/android.os.Debug(21072): failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-09 13:26:16.535: D/AndroidRuntime(21072): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
07-09 13:26:16.549: I/ActivityManager(419): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.pittan.androidwearble/.MainActivity} from uid 2000 on display 0
07-09 13:26:16.550: V/WindowManager(419): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{591d85e token=Token{108e4d99 ActivityRecord{3768b6e0 u0 com.example.pittan.androidwearble/.MainActivity t386}}} to stack=1 task=386 at 0
07-09 13:26:16.552: W/IsClosedInputStream(569): tried to close more than once
07-09 13:26:16.555: D/AndroidRuntime(21072): Shutting down VM
07-09 13:26:16.566: I/art(21072): Debugger is no longer active
07-09 13:26:16.623: I/ActivityManager(419): Start proc 21089:com.example.pittan.androidwearble/u0a23 for activity com.example.pittan.androidwearble/.MainActivity
07-09 13:26:16.635: I/art(21089): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
07-09 13:26:16.690: V/ActivityManager(419): Display changed displayId=0
07-09 13:26:16.717: W/ResourcesManager(21089): Asset path '/system/framework/com.google.android.wearable.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
07-09 13:26:16.766: D/AltBeacon Sample(21089): ==========================iBeaconWear==========================
07-09 13:26:16.766: D/AltBeacon Sample(21089): onCreateメソッドが実行されました
07-09 13:26:16.854: D/OpenGLRenderer(21089): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
07-09 13:26:16.860: D/ION(21089): config: version(0x10001) secure(0xf000) 256M(0x221) fast(0x608) hwwr(0x4)
07-09 13:26:16.863: I/MM_DEVICE(21089): Waiting for mm thread to come up
07-09 13:26:16.863: I/MM_DEVICE(21089): mm_device_thread starting
07-09 13:26:16.871: D/Atlas(21089): Validating map...
07-09 13:26:16.883: W/WindowManager(419): Failed looking up window
07-09 13:26:16.883: W/WindowManager(419): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@15a1c5a4 does not exist
07-09 13:26:16.883: W/WindowManager(419):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8562)
07-09 13:26:16.883: W/WindowManager(419):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.pokeDrawLock(WindowManagerService.java:3004)
07-09 13:26:16.883: W/WindowManager(419):   at com.android.server.wm.Session.pokeDrawLock(Session.java:482)
07-09 13:26:16.883: W/WindowManager(419):   at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact(IWindowSession.java:675)
07-09 13:26:16.883: W/WindowManager(419):   at com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact(Session.java:130)
07-09 13:26:16.883: W/WindowManager(419):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
07-09 13:26:16.886: V/WindowManager(419): Adding window Window{f14f0d u0 com.example.pittan.androidwearble/com.example.pittan.androidwearble.MainActivity} at 2 of 4 (after Window{3ab684d9 u0 com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.home.HomeActivity})
07-09 13:26:16.915: W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator(21089): App has no android.permission.INTERNET permission.  Cannot check for distance model updates
07-09 13:26:17.026: W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator(21089): Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
07-09 13:26:17.026: W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator(21089): Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
07-09 13:26:17.080: I/art(21089): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11287(612KB) AllocSpace objects, 10(186KB) LOS objects, 10% free, 6MB/7MB, paused 11.596ms total 67.871ms
07-09 13:26:17.113: D/(21089): HwMemAllocatorImpl Static Counters 0 0
07-09 13:26:17.113: D/(21089): HwMemAllocatorImpl[ae4560a8] totalDeviceAllocSize[0] totalFree[0] maxFree[0] in numSlabs[0]
07-09 13:26:17.118: I/OpenGLRenderer(21089): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-09 13:26:17.127: D/OpenGLRenderer(21089): Enabling debug mode 0
07-09 13:26:17.147: D/AltBeacon Sample(21089): ==========================iBeaconWear==========================
07-09 13:26:17.147: D/AltBeacon Sample(21089): in Ambient
07-09 13:26:17.385: D/BluetoothManagerService(419): Message: 20
07-09 13:26:17.386: D/BluetoothManagerService(419): Added callback: android.bluetooth.IBluetoothManagerCallback$Stub$Proxy@b93150e:true
07-09 13:26:17.421: D/BtGatt.GattService(1006): registerClient() - UUID=246c1301-999a-40be-8680-3dc38b188bdb
07-09 13:26:17.423: D/BtGatt.GattService(1006): onClientRegistered() - UUID=246c1301-999a-40be-8680-3dc38b188bdb, clientIf=4
07-09 13:26:17.423: D/BluetoothLeScanner(21089): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=4
07-09 13:26:17.424: D/BtGatt.GattService(1006): start scan with filters
07-09 13:26:17.427: D/BtGatt.ScanManager(1006): handling starting scan
07-09 13:26:17.428: I/ActivityManager(419): Displayed com.example.pittan.androidwearble/.MainActivity: +872ms
07-09 13:26:17.430: D/BtGatt.ScanManager(1006): configureRegularScanParams() - queue=1
07-09 13:26:17.430: D/BtGatt.ScanManager(1006): configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=2 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=-2147483648
07-09 13:26:17.456: I/DisplayManagerService(419): Display device changed: DisplayDeviceInfo{"内蔵スクリーン": uniqueId="local:0", 320 x 320, 60.0 fps, supportedRefreshRates [60.0], density 280, 280.275 x 280.275 dpi, appVsyncOff 0, presDeadline 17666667, touch INTERNAL, rotation 0, type BUILT_IN, state DOZE, FLAG_DEFAULT_DISPLAY, FLAG_ROTATES_WITH_CONTENT, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
07-09 13:26:17.458: V/ActivityManager(419): Display changed displayId=0
07-09 13:26:17.481: D/SurfaceFlinger(142): Set power mode=1, type=0 flinger=0xb7242550
07-09 13:26:17.481: E/bcm_java.hwcomposer(142): blanking 0
07-09 13:26:17.520: D/AltBeacon Sample(21089): ==========================領域ステータス変更==========================
07-09 13:26:17.520: D/AltBeacon Sample(21089): ==========================領域に侵入==========================
07-09 13:26:17.578: I/DisplayManagerService(419): Display device changed: DisplayDeviceInfo{"内蔵スクリーン": uniqueId="local:0", 320 x 320, 60.0 fps, supportedRefreshRates [60.0], density 280, 280.275 x 280.275 dpi, appVsyncOff 0, presDeadline 17666667, touch INTERNAL, rotation 0, type BUILT_IN, state DOZE_SUSPEND, FLAG_DEFAULT_DISPLAY, FLAG_ROTATES_WITH_CONTENT, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
07-09 13:26:17.581: D/SurfaceFlinger(142): Set power mode=3, type=0 flinger=0xb7242550
07-09 13:26:17.582: E/bcm_java.hwcomposer(142): blanking 0
07-09 13:26:17.584: V/ActivityManager(419): Display changed displayId=0
07-09 13:26:18.550: D/BtGatt.GattService(1006): stopScan() - queue size =1
07-09 13:26:18.553: D/BtGatt.ScanManager(1006): stop scan
07-09 13:26:18.559: D/BtGatt.GattService(1006): unregisterClient() - clientIf=4
07-09 13:26:18.554: D/BtGatt.ScanManager(1006): configureRegularScanParams() - queue=0
07-09 13:26:18.560: D/BtGatt.ScanManager(1006): configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=-2147483648 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=2
07-09 13:26:18.560: D/BtGatt.ScanManager(1006): configureRegularScanParams() - queue emtpy, scan stopped
07-09 13:26:18.577: D/BtGatt.GattService(1006): registerClient() - UUID=85a3e0dc-73ae-4d19-8a06-af963b5e8ef9
07-09 13:26:18.577: D/BtGatt.GattService(1006): onClientRegistered() - UUID=85a3e0dc-73ae-4d19-8a06-af963b5e8ef9, clientIf=4
07-09 13:26:18.578: D/BluetoothLeScanner(21089): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=4
07-09 13:26:18.579: D/BtGatt.GattService(1006): start scan with filters
07-09 13:26:18.580: D/BtGatt.ScanManager(1006): handling starting scan
07-09 13:26:18.583: D/BtGatt.ScanManager(1006): configureRegularScanParams() - queue=1
07-09 13:26:18.583: D/BtGatt.ScanManager(1006): configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=2 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=-2147483648
07-09 13:26:19.686: D/TaskPersister(419): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=385_task.xml
07-09 13:26:22.318: I/PowerManagerService(419): Waking up from dozing (uid 1000)...
07-09 13:26:22.320: I/BRCM PowerHAL(419): BRCM PowerHAL: set interactive --> screen on
07-09 13:26:22.323: V/KeyguardServiceDelegate(419): onScreenTurnedOn(showListener = com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager$2@350fd22)
07-09 13:26:22.347: D/PowerManagerService-JNI(419): Excessive delay in setInteractive(true) while turning screen on: 27ms
07-09 13:26:22.347: E/InputMethodManagerService(419): Ignoring setImeWindowStatus due to an invalid token. uid:1000 token:null
07-09 13:26:22.355: V/KeyguardServiceDelegate(419): **** SHOWN CALLED ****
07-09 13:26:22.362: E/WifiStateMachine(419): cancelDelayedScan -> 289
07-09 13:26:22.376: D/audio_hw(154): ENTERING adev_set_parameters() screen_state=on
07-09 13:26:22.376: V/audio_hw(154): setFMParameters: screen_state=on 
07-09 13:26:22.376: V/audio_hw(154): LEAVING adev_set_parameters()
07-09 13:26:22.429: D/DeepAmbientRecognition(569): onDestroy
07-09 13:26:22.517: I/DisplayManagerService(419): Display device changed: DisplayDeviceInfo{"内蔵スクリーン": uniqueId="local:0", 320 x 320, 60.0 fps, supportedRefreshRates [60.0], density 280, 280.275 x 280.275 dpi, appVsyncOff 0, presDeadline 17666667, touch INTERNAL, rotation 0, type BUILT_IN, state ON, FLAG_DEFAULT_DISPLAY, FLAG_ROTATES_WITH_CONTENT, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
07-09 13:26:22.519: V/ActivityManager(419): Display changed displayId=0
07-09 13:26:22.519: D/SurfaceFlinger(142): Set power mode=2, type=0 flinger=0xb7242550
07-09 13:26:22.519: E/bcm_java.hwcomposer(142): blanking 0
07-09 13:26:22.526: I/DreamManagerService(419): Gently waking up from dream.
07-09 13:26:22.527: V/DreamService[AmbientDream](802): wakeUp(): fromSystem=true, mWaking=false, mFinished=false
07-09 13:26:22.527: V/DreamService[AmbientDream](802): finish(): mFinished=false
07-09 13:26:22.527: I/DreamManagerService(419): Leaving dreamland.
07-09 13:26:22.528: I/DreamController(419): Stopping dream: name=ComponentInfo{com.google.android.wearable.ambient/com.google.android.wearable.ambient.AmbientDream}, isTest=false, canDoze=true, userId=0
07-09 13:26:22.532: V/DreamService[AmbientDream](802): detach(): Calling onDreamingStopped()
07-09 13:26:22.532: I/AmbientService(802): Ambient Stopping
07-09 13:26:22.542: D/AltBeacon Sample(21089): ==========================iBeaconWear==========================
07-09 13:26:22.542: D/AltBeacon Sample(21089): did exit Ambient
07-09 13:26:22.551: V/DreamService[AmbientDream](802): onDestroy()
07-09 13:26:22.551: W/AmbientDream(802): exitAmbient: Already finished dreaming.
07-09 13:26:22.560: W/AmbientDream(802): exitAmbient: Already finished dreaming.
07-09 13:26:24.543: I/PowerManagerService(419): Going to sleep due to sleep button (uid 1000)...
07-09 13:26:24.548: I/DreamManagerService(419): Entering dreamland.
07-09 13:26:24.548: I/PowerManagerService(419): Dozing...
07-09 13:26:24.549: I/DreamController(419): Starting dream: name=ComponentInfo{com.google.android.wearable.ambient/com.google.android.wearable.ambient.AmbientDream}, isTest=false, canDoze=true, userId=0
07-09 13:26:24.563: E/InputMethodManagerService(419): Ignoring setImeWindowStatus due to an invalid token. uid:1000 token:null
07-09 13:26:24.568: E/InputMethodManagerService(419): Ignoring setImeWindowStatus due to an invalid token. uid:1000 token:null
07-09 13:26:24.572: D/audio_hw(154): ENTERING adev_set_parameters() screen_state=off
07-09 13:26:24.572: V/audio_hw(154): setFMParameters: screen_state=off 
07-09 13:26:24.572: V/audio_hw(154): LEAVING adev_set_parameters()
07-09 13:26:24.575: E/WifiStateMachine(419): cancelDelayedScan -> 290
07-09 13:26:24.611: V/ActivityManager(419): Display changed displayId=0
07-09 13:26:24.653: W/IsClosedInputStream(569): tried to close more than once
07-09 13:26:24.655: V/DreamService[AmbientDream](802): onBind() intent = Intent { act=android.service.dreams.DreamService flg=0x800000 cmp=com.google.android.wearable.ambient/.AmbientDream }
07-09 13:26:24.659: I/AmbientService(802): Ambient Created
07-09 13:26:24.659: V/DreamService[AmbientDream](802): Calling onDreamingStarted()
07-09 13:26:24.659: I/AmbientService(802): Ambient Starting
07-09 13:26:24.686: V/audio_hw(154): ENTERING adev_open_input_stream() channels = 1 channel mask = 16  format = 1  sample_rate = 8000
07-09 13:26:24.686: V/audio_hw(154): ENTERING check_input_parameters
07-09 13:26:24.686: V/audio_hw(154): LEAVING check_input_parameters ret = 0, channels = 1, channel mask = 16, format = 1, sample_rate = 8000
07-09 13:26:24.686: V/audio_hw(154): dump.audio.pcmin = OFF
07-09 13:26:24.686: V/audio_hw(154): Data Dump is disabled for input stream
07-09 13:26:24.686: V/audio_hw(154): dump.audio.voip = OFF
07-09 13:26:24.686: V/audio_hw(154): Data Dump is disabled for voip input
07-09 13:26:24.686: D/audio_hw(154): In adev_open_input_stream devices = 80000004, channel_count = 1
07-09 13:26:24.686: V/audio_hw(154): select_alsa_input_dev:SpeechIn
07-09 13:26:24.686: D/audio_hw(154): config->sample_rate = 8000, devices = 80000004
07-09 13:26:24.690: D/alsa_pcm(154): channels = 1, Fs = 8000, period_size = 0x800, periods = 2
07-09 13:26:24.690: D/alsa_pcm(154): pcm_handle->bufSize_bytes = 0x1000 samples = 0x1000
07-09 13:26:24.691: V/audio_hw(154): LEAVING adev_open_input_stream() channels = 1 format = 1 sample_rate = 8000 pcm device = 80000004
07-09 13:26:24.693: I/DASH - em718x(419): update_fifo_size: 'acc' rate 16000000 ns, latency 100000000 ns, fifo 0
07-09 13:26:24.694: I/DASH - em718x(419): update_fifo_size: 'acc' rate 16000000 ns, latency 100000000 ns, fifo 5
07-09 13:26:24.702: I/AudioFlinger(154): AudioFlinger's thread 0xb590d008 ready to run
07-09 13:26:24.702: D/audio_in(154): ENTERING in_standby() for device -2147483644
07-09 13:26:24.702: D/audio_in(154): LEAVING in_standby() for device -2147483644
07-09 13:26:24.707: D/audio_in(154): ENTERING in_set_parameters() input_source=6;routing=-2147483644
07-09 13:26:24.717: D/audio_in(154): ENTERING start_input_stream(), in->main_channels=16, in->requested_rate=8000
07-09 13:26:24.717: V/alsa_hal_controller(154): ENTERING set_app_profile()
07-09 13:26:24.717: V/alsa_hal_controller(154): ENTERING enable_app_profile 7
07-09 13:26:24.717: E/alsa_control(154): Control not initialized
07-09 13:26:24.717: V/alsa_hal_controller(154): LEAVING set_app_profile() status = 1 profile 7  enable 1
07-09 13:26:24.717: V/alsa_hal_controller(154): ENTERING select_input_device() current device = 0x80000004 new device = 0x80000004 in = 0xb8c64448
07-09 13:26:24.717: V/alsa_hal_controller(154): no need to switch device in_cur_dev = -2147483644, new device = -2147483644, mode = 0
07-09 13:26:24.717: V/alsa_hal_controller(154): LEAVING select_input_device()
07-09 13:26:24.717: V/audio_hw(154): select_alsa_input_dev:SpeechIn
07-09 13:26:24.720: D/alsa_pcm(154): channels = 1, Fs = 8000, period_size = 0x800, periods = 2
07-09 13:26:24.720: D/alsa_pcm(154): pcm_handle->bufSize_bytes = 0x1000 samples = 0x1000
07-09 13:26:24.720: D/audio_in(154): LEAVING start_input_stream() in->need_echo_reference=0
07-09 13:26:24.765: D/BtGatt.GattService(1006): stopScan() - queue size =1
07-09 13:26:24.765: D/BtGatt.ScanManager(1006): stop scan
07-09 13:26:24.766: D/BtGatt.ScanManager(1006): configureRegularScanParams() - queue=0
07-09 13:26:24.766: D/BtGatt.ScanManager(1006): configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=-2147483648 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=2
07-09 13:26:24.766: D/BtGatt.ScanManager(1006): configureRegularScanParams() - queue emtpy, scan stopped
07-09 13:26:24.767: D/BtGatt.GattService(1006): unregisterClient() - clientIf=4
07-09 13:26:24.769: D/BluetoothLeScanner(21089): could not find callback wrapper
07-09 13:26:24.780: D/AltBeacon Sample(21089): ===================Destroy======================
07-09 13:26:24.794: I/DASH - em718x(419): update_fifo_size: 'acc' rate 64000000 ns, latency 100000000 ns, fifo 0
07-09 13:26:24.815: D/(21089): HwMemAllocatorImpl Static Counters 2 0
07-09 13:26:24.815: D/(21089): HwMemAllocatorImpl[ae4560a8] totalDeviceAllocSize[3145728] totalFree[305408] maxFree[221440] in numSlabs[2]
07-09 13:26:24.815: D/(21089):  HwMemBlock[b79681b8] pa[0xb1a00000] va[0xac657000] size[524288] alloc[440320] free[83968] maxFree[79872] mode[1016] refCnt[5] fullList[5] freeList[2] 
07-09 13:26:24.815: D/(21089):  HwMemBlock[b7995898] pa[0xb3e00000] va[0xac09b000] size[2621440] alloc[2400000] free[221440] maxFree[221440] mode[1016] refCnt[2] fullList[2] freeList[1] 
07-09 13:26:24.831: I/DASH - em718x(419): update_fifo_size: 'acc' rate 64000000 ns, latency 100000000 ns, fifo 0
07-09 13:26:25.306: D/audio_in(154): ENTERING in_standby() for device -2147483644
07-09 13:26:25.313: V/alsa_hal_controller(154): ENTERING set_app_profile()
07-09 13:26:25.313: V/alsa_hal_controller(154): ENTERING enable_app_profile 7
07-09 13:26:25.313: E/alsa_control(154): Control not initialized
07-09 13:26:25.313: V/alsa_hal_controller(154): LEAVING set_app_profile() status = 1 profile 7  enable 0
07-09 13:26:25.313: D/audio_in(154): LEAVING in_standby() for device -2147483644
07-09 13:26:25.313: V/audio_hw(154): ENTERING adev_close_input_stream()
07-09 13:26:25.314: D/audio_in(154): ENTERING in_standby() for device -2147483644
07-09 13:26:25.314: D/audio_in(154): LEAVING in_standby() for device -2147483644
07-09 13:26:25.314: V/audio_hw(154): HPF FILTER CLOSED
07-09 13:26:25.314: V/audio_hw(154): LEAVING adev_close_input_stream()
07-09 13:26:25.328: I/DisplayManagerService(419): Display device changed: DisplayDeviceInfo{"内蔵スクリーン": uniqueId="local:0", 320 x 320, 60.0 fps, supportedRefreshRates [60.0], density 280, 280.275 x 280.275 dpi, appVsyncOff 0, presDeadline 17666667, touch INTERNAL, rotation 0, type BUILT_IN, state DOZE_SUSPEND, FLAG_DEFAULT_DISPLAY, FLAG_ROTATES_WITH_CONTENT, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
07-09 13:26:25.329: V/ActivityManager(419): Display changed displayId=0
07-09 13:26:25.336: D/SurfaceFlinger(142): Set power mode=3, type=0 flinger=0xb7242550
07-09 13:26:25.336: E/bcm_java.hwcomposer(142): blanking 0
07-09 13:26:25.342: I/BRCM PowerHAL(419): BRCM PowerHAL: set interactive --> screen off
```

Comment: Please post a stack trace produced when the application ends.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I pasted my stack trace.

Comment: It appears this is an issue with the application life cycle on Ambient mode on AndroidWear.  I am not an expert on this.  Perhaps somebody who is can comment on to what extent background services are allowed to run in Ambient mode.

Comment: @Pittan, Hi I am facing some issue on the same so  can u share your sample application code with me??